# Puzzle: Give an algorithm for finding a frog that jumps along the number line

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, algorithms, puzzle

You are playing a game, your goal in this game is to catch a frog that's leaping between natural numbers.

At first, the frog is found at the number $a \in \mathbb N$ which is not known to you.
Each turn, you take a guess at where the frog is found.

If you are right - you win.

If you are wrong - the frog leaps $b \in \mathbb N$ numbers to the right. Meaning, if you got the first guess wrong, the frog is now at $a+b$. If you get the guess wrong again, it's now at $a+2b$.

Neither $a$ or $b$ are known to you. All you know is that they are natural numbers.

Propose an algorithm that will find the frog in a finite number of steps, regardless of what $a$ and $b$ are.

Additional challenge: Same question, but now $a,b \in \mathbb Z$.

Comment: This sounds like a (Martin Gardner?) problem I have heard before, only that one involved bombing a submarine instead of findind a frog.

Comment: I'm an eternal pacifist...

Comment: Leave the frogs alone.  Experiment on yourselves.

Comment: If you know the $b$, the algorithm is easy.
Firstly say that the frog is at the 1st position. 
If you're wrong then say that it's at $2+b$. 
Again if you're wrong then say that it's at $3+2\cdot b$.
Each time when you're wrong say that the frog is at $(k+1)+k\cdot b$.
You will surely win in mostly $a$ steps, so the algorithm's complexity is O(a).

Comment: You do not know $b$. But regardless I would like to hear your proposed solution for that case. Even though it is not relevant to our question.

Comment: If you do now know the $b$, then you should try all the possible $b$.
Firstly, try b = 1 and say 1st position.
If you're wrong try b = 2, and as you already wasted 1 turn the wrog is probably 2 numbers away to the right.
Then try b = 3 and so on.
The algorithm somewhen will find the correct answer.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For fixed $a$ and $b$, after $m$ steps, the frog will be at $a + mb$ if you haven't guessed right yet. The set of pairs $(a, b) \in \mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$ is countable, so you can enumerate it, say as $(a_0, b_0), (a_1, b_1), \ldots$. Now guess $a_m + mb_m$ at step $m$ and you are bound to guess right eventually.

Comment: You got there before I did.

Comment: @Mark Bennet: better luck next time!

Comment: This even works if the frog's next position were determined by a Turing machine rather than a linear progression. (Even if the frog is privy to the positions you've guessed)

Comment: @Meelo: I don't see how you would deal with non-termination (unless you imposed a time bound on the frog's computation).

Comment: How does this work if you don't know what a and b are?

Comment: @SomeGuy: the algorithm performs a search to find out what $a$ and $b$ are (by enumerating all the possibilities and performing tests to find out which possibility actually applies).